# Insert into respective column through Java HashMap()

Tags: java, spring, hashmap, primary-key, getter-setter

I have a jsp page that gives me a dropdown

```
<select name="position_id">
   <c:forEach items="${positionList}" var="entry" >
      <option value="${entry.value}">${entry.value.id}</option>
   </c:forEach>
</select>
```

When the user selects a value from the drop down I am currently getting it as **position {id:1, Description: java}**

which I wanted to pass it to a model with columns id(PK, int) and description(String) and the model has a constructor with parameter description.

Now when it goes to the model it is trying to insert the values as **position {id:1, Description: java}** to **Description** variable.

But I wanted it to go and set the respective values to id and description.

Can someone help me out with this issue.

Comment: Is this select tag inside a form tag. If yes the why are you not using spring form tag library??

Comment: Could you please post the code what u have tried. Also please put code for controller method signature.

Comment: I tried with Spring form library but I couldn't get the position object containing Id and description to return from the dropdown when selected.